# Dynamically Adding to JArray generates repeated data

Tags: c#, json

When I write this code:

```
   string[] title= {"title1","title2","title3","title4"};
   int[] iid= {124,122,333,234};

   dynamic bucket = new JObject();
   bucket.bucket = "Parking Lot";
   bucket.roadmap = new JArray();

   dynamic issue = new JObject();
   dynamic json2 = new JArray(bucket);

   for(int i=0; i<title.Length; i++) {
        issue.title = title[i];
        issue.iid = iid[i];
        issue.order = i;
        bucket.roadmap.Add(issue);
   }

   Console.WriteLine(json2.ToString());
```

My result is:

```
   [
     {
       "bucket": "Parking Lot",
       "roadmap": [
         {
           "title": "title4",
           "iid": 234,
           "order": 3
         },
         {
           "title": "title2",
           "iid": 122,
           "order": 1
         },
         {
           "title": "title3",
           "iid": 333,
           "order": 2
         },
         {
           "title": "title4",
           "iid": 234,
           "order": 3
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
```

The first and last "roadmap" JObjects got repeated. There is a way if dynamically generate this JSON with their unique values I want to pass?

I also tried to do it non-dynamically.

```
    JArray bucket = new JObject();
    bucket.Add("bucket","Parking Lot");
    bucket.Add("order", new JArray());

    JObject issue = new JObject();
    ...
```

But I could not find a way to select "bucket.order.Add" to add issues to that JArray.

In the end, I am just trying to loop through a JArray with a bunch of data and I want to separate it from their bucket type, extract each issue value and store it in a new JSON, with the structure shown here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new issue object before adding to the array.

```
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        issue = new JObject();
        issue.title = "Elbow\"";
        issue.iid = 123;
        issue.order = i;
        bucket.roadmap.Add(issue);
   }
```

Comment: I felt stupid seeing how simple the solution was... Thank you so much

Comment: What??  I find this very surprising.  Why does the original version duplicate just "4"?  There needs to be an explanation, don't you think?  Something unexpected is happening with the duplication of the item.  For example, instead of creating a new `JObject` each time, you can just move the `Add` to the top of the loop and set its properties after it is added.  This helps reveal some of the "magic" that is going on.  I'm hoping for a bigger, more detailed explanation.

Comment: It's as if the object is only duplicated if it already exists in the list, otherwise it is added as is and the reference to the object is still valid (you can change its properties after it is added.)